# invalid DOM Nesting error in React component that is trying to display a list of links

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I'm trying to render a list of links in my React component:

```
              <Tbody> 
                {_.map(memberContractsOnDisplay, (contract) => (
                  <Link to='/groups' key={contract.member_id}>
                    <Tr>
                      <Td>{contract.member_id}</Td>
                      <Td>{contract.name}</Td>
                      <Td>{contract.pricing_version}</Td>
                      <Td>{contract.seller_type}</Td>
                      <Td>{contract.selling_enabled}</Td>
                      <Td><BillablePopUp passedProp_is_billable={contract.
                        is_billable}/></Td>
                    </Tr>
                  </Link>
                ))}
              </Tbody>
```

It is working but I am getting the following error in my Chrome console:

```
react-with-addons.js:20728 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a child of <tbody>. See ProxyComponent > (unknown) > tbody > Link > a.
```

and

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <tr> cannot appear as a child of <a>. See ProxyComponent > Link > a > (unknown) > tr.
```

What can I do to remove this error? I tried wrapping the stuff in another div but that just caused other errors.

Comment: It's not an error, it's a warning. tbody tag is not meant to contain <link> aka <a>. It's just letting you know you are using invalid html. Some browsers it may work fine, other browsers it may not.

Comment: What you *can* do though, is add an `onClick` action on your `<Tr>` component which triggers navigation.

Comment: Simply what the warning says: you can't have a <tr> in an <a>. Tables consist of rows and columns, not links or divs. So, solutions are to either put the entire table in the <a>, use multiple <a>s (one in each of the <td>s) or don't use a table.